# can't write timestamps in PostgreSQL using RPostgres dbWriteTable

Tags: r, dplyr, r-dbi

I'm trying to write an R `tibble` object (or `data.frame`) into a `Postgres` database using the `RPostgres` package. Following the documentation, I'm trying to use the `dbWriteTable` function.

However, I realized that there's no specification of `field.types` in the method. Here I provide a minimal example where you can see the method failing when the input has a `POSIXct` timestamp (and passing when the timestamp is interpreted as a character).

```
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)
library(RPostgres)
library(tibble)

conn <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
  host = url$host,
  port = url$port,
  dbname = url$dbname,
  user = url$user,
  password = url$password
)

test <- tibble(
  words = c("hallo","ja", "nein"),
  value = c(3,4,5),
  time= as.POSIXct(c("2016-05-04 04:32","2016-06-02 09:37","2016-07-12 10:43")))
test2 <- tibble(
  words = c("hallo","ja", "nein"),
  value = c(3,4,5),
  time= c("2016-05-04 04:32","2016-06-02 09:37","2016-07-12 10:43"))

dbWriteTable(conn = conn, name = "words", value = test)
> Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) :
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type real: "2016-05-04 04:32:00"
> CONTEXT:  COPY words, line 1, column time: "2016-05-04 04:32:00"

dbWriteTable(conn = conn, name = "words2", value = test2)
> [1] TRUE
```

Does anyone know of a better way to write a table with timestamps in `Postgres` using `R`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `PostgreSQL` driver in the `RPostgreSQL` package works. Also, the format of the third timestamp does not match default for as.POSIXct - too many digits for hour. So I changed `"2016-07-12 010:43"` to `"2016-07-12 10:43"` and you should find it works fine.

```
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(tibble)

#connect to db    
url <- list(user="postgres",password="postgres",dbname="test")

conn <- dbConnect(drv="PostgreSQL", user=url$user, password=url$password, dbname = url$dbname)


test <- tibble(
  words = c("hallo","ja", "nein"),
  value = c(3,4,5),
  time= as.POSIXct(c("2016-05-04 04:32","2016-06-02 09:37","2016-07-12 10:43")))
test2 <- tibble(
  words = c("hallo","ja", "nein"),
  value = c(3,4,5),
  time= c("2016-05-04 04:32","2016-06-02 09:37","2016-07-12 010:43"))


dbWriteTable(conn = conn, name = "words", value = test)
```

> [1] TRUE

```
dbWriteTable(conn = conn, name = "words2", value = test2)
```

> [1] TRUE

```
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment Chris. I fixed the typo in the original example, which unfortunately doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You might try PostgreSQL driver in the RPostgreSQL package. Your example works fine for me. I can edit my post if it would help.

Comment: This made me re-visit `RPostgreSQL`, which solved some ssl connection problems (which weren't even described in this post). Thanks Chris!